# sendinput string in rust

Tags: winapi, rust, sendinput

I made a C++ program that uses the Windows `SendInput()` API to fire a string. The code can be seen below and is functional.

```cpp
std::vector<INPUT> vec;
for (auto ch : this->buffer)
{
  input = { 0 };
  input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
  input.ki.wScan = ch;
  vec.push_back(input);
  input.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  vec.push_back(input);
}
SendInput(vec.size(), vec.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
```

Where the variable `buffer` is the string I want to release.

I am trying to replicate this code for the Rust language, however I am having difficulties understanding how to use `SendInput()`. Can someone help me?

In Rust, for just 1 character, I'm trying to use the following code:

```rust
#[cfg(windows)] extern crate winapi;

#[cfg(windows)]

fn main() {
    let mut input = winapi::INPUT {
        type_ : winapi::INPUT_KEYBOARD,
        u: winapi::KEYBDINPUT {
            wScan: 'c',
            dwFlags: 0x4, // KEYEVENTF_UNICODE in c++
        }
    };
    winapi::um::winapi::SendInput(1, &mut input, 1);
}
```

Comment: Per the [`SendInput()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), the last parameter is the byte size of a single `INPUT` structure.  Your C++ code is correctly telling `SendInput()` that an `INPUT` is `sizeof(INPUT)` bytes, but your Rust code is telling `SendInput()` that an `INPUT` is 1 byte, which is wrong.